# Userscripts - подключение в качестве библиотеки

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, chrome-extension, chromium

Возможно ли подключение одного Userscript из другого в качестве библиотеки? Не по ссылке на локальный/удалённый файл через `@require`, а "прозрачно", по имени.

В Tampermonkey под Chrome хочу иметь установленный Userscript "Z" с базовыми функциями, которые можно будет вызвать из других, запущенных в Tampermonkey, скриптов (`function_y = Z->funcrion_x()` и т. п.).